# Close Form1 If FileExists+ Open Form2

Tags: vb.net, forms

I try to close or hide the Form cnx if a file exist and open the Form Product.
But Something is wrong and i don't understand why this dont work.

```
    Private Sub cnx_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    strFileName = "app.txt"
    strBasePath = Application.StartupPath
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(strFileName) = True Then
        Product.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(strFileName) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("File App.config is Missing! Create a new Database.",
            "Something is Wrong!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have asked 7 questions, gotten 7 answers but accepted none.  Accepting answers - and voting - helps others find good posts.  The [tour] explains how SO works.

Comment: You cannot Hide() a form in the Load event.  The Load event fires because you used Show().  You have to go back and find the code that created the form, that's where the If-statement belongs.  But you probably want to keep doing this, use Close() instead and Project > Properties > Application tab > Shutdown mode = when last form closes.

Comment: Yes it's that.... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, although probably not optimal.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    hideForm(Me)
    Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub hideForm(form As Form)
    form.Opacity = 0.0F
    form.ShowInTaskbar = False
End Sub
```

Also remember to add under Form2 or your program will stay open after closing Form2.

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Form1.Close()
End Sub
```